# Invalid read of size 1 in strstr() using valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind, strstr

I'm inspecting some piece of code with valgrind and I get this error:

```
==7001== Invalid read of size 1
==7001==    at 0x402E21B: strstr (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==7001==    by 0x8049742: replace_in_file (functions.c:191)
==7001==    by 0x8049C55: parse_dir (functions.c:295)
==7001==    by 0x8049059: main (main.c:214)
==7001==  Address 0x42018c3 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==7001==    at 0x402B018: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==7001==    by 0x80496EC: replace_in_file (functions.c:183)
==7001==    by 0x8049C55: parse_dir (functions.c:295)
==7001==    by 0x8049059: main (main.c:214)
```

The code snippet looks as follows:

```
long int replace_in_file(char **sets, FILE *file, char *path, const char *mode){
    long int n = 0, size = 0, len, remaining_len;

    char *buffer,
         *found,
         *before,
         *after;

    size = file_size(file);
    if(-1 != size){

        buffer = malloc(size * sizeof(char));

        rewind(file);
        fread(buffer, 1, size, file);

        int i=0;
        do{
            do{
                found = strstr(buffer, sets[i]); // LINE 191
                if(NULL != found && '\0' != sets[i][0]){

//rest of code...
```

I cannot realise why I get that error, because everything works as expected and in the debugger every variable seems fine.

What is wrong, how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you guarantee that `buffer` is Nul-terminated after the `fread()`? I notice you don't `bzero()` it or anything.

Comment: How many (char *) pointers are in the (sets) array?  Is it possible that sets[i] has a value for i that puts it outside of the (sets) array?  Also, how is it guaranteed that (buffer) will be NUL-terminated?  fread() won't do that for you...

Comment: Any chance file_size is returning 0? I would use if(size > 0) in your conditional.

Comment: Solved, @chrisaycock, add your answer so I can accept it, that was the problem. Jeremy Friesner, I saw your answer after solving it.

Comment: Alright, I posted it as an answer. You should also upvote [FatalError](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10435825/478288) since he found the same bug.

Comment: Yep, upvoted everyone that touched that subject of nul-termiantion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `buffer` is not nul-terminated. Usually, you can just `bzero()` it before the `fread()` to ensure that it will work with `strstr()` and similar functions.

Answer (score 6):

`fread()` does *not* nul-terminate the data it reads, but `strstr()` expects a nul-terminated string. You should allocate size+1 bytes and explicitly add the nul-terminator to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

from what I read in my manpage, `fread()` does not `NULL`-terminate its result according to C89 - and it does not on my system, either - so `strstr()` will simply read over the end of `buffer` unless you terminate it e.g. like so

```
buffer = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));
memset(buffer, '\0', size + 1);
```

(which has the advantage of also terminating it in case fread fails to read the whole file)

a sidenote: since you already use `sizeof(char)` in your `malloc()` call, you might also consider replacing the `1` in the `fread()` for sake of consistency.